# Review audit ignores closereason filter

Tags: bug, review-audits

I think there is a small loophole in review audits. It basically ignores closereason filter which I've selected.

For example when I'm selecting filter *only duplicates* (or any other), the audit will ignore the filter by showing non-related questions to that filter such as *too broad*, which obviously indicates it is audit without even looking on the question it-self. I haven't tested if the same is happening with tag filter. However I've never seen the review audit which is flagged as duplicate.

[image: stackoverflow - This question has been flagged as: too broad - screenshot]
[image: stackoverflow - This question has been flagged as: too broad - screenshot]